# Unmarshalling xml tag with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ProductItem xmlns="http://providers.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/meta/" urn="urn:product-item:910796-76" url="http://immix-test2.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/en-US/product-item/910796-76.xml">
<partNumber>910796-76</partNumber>
<inventoryItemId>560427</inventoryItemId>
<nicInventoryItemId>765430</nicInventoryItemId>
<name />
<description>LABVIEW CORE 2 SELF-PACED ONLINE TRAINING (6 MONTHS ACCESS)</description>
<isCustomerFacing>true</isCustomerFacing>
<itemType>CE</itemType>
<partType>Training Program</partType>
<bookingsClassName />
<bookingsClassCode />
<lifecyclePhase>Released</lifecyclePhase>
<salesClass />
<firstOrderableDate />
<locale>en-US</locale>
<ngpmProductHierarchy />
<productRevisions url="http://immix-test2.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/en-US/product-item/910796-76/productRevisions.xml" />
<serviceOptionsForProduct url="http://immix-test2.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/en-US/product-item/910796-76/serviceOptionsForProduct.xml" />
<serviceOptionsByService url="http://immix-test2.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/en-US/product-item/910796-76/serviceOptionsByService.xml" />
<productFeatures url="http://immix-test2.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/en-US/product-item/910796-76/productFeatures.xml" />
 </ProductItem>
```

I'm trying to get the description label. This is my java code.

```
package com.ni.apps.elearningrest.client;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ProductItem")
public class DescriptionDTO {

    private String description;
    private String uri;


    @XmlElement(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }               
}
```

But I keep getting a "Unexpected element (uri: "http://providers.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/meta/, local:"ProductItem"). Expected elements are <{}ProductItem>" error. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the namespace to the JAXB annotation:

`@XmlRootElement(name = "ProductItem", namespace="http://providers.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/meta/")`

Comment: Ok, that took care of the error, but now, I'm not getting the description. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, fixed... I also added the namespace on the @XmlElement. It looks like this @XmlElement(name = "description", namespace = "htt p://providers.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/meta/"). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While you could specify the namespace property on the `@XmlRootEleemnt` and `@XmlElement` annotations, I would recommend leveraging the `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify a default namespace instead.

**com/ni/apps/elearningrest/client/package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://providers.natinst.com/pdi-rest/1.0/meta/", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.ni.apps.elearningrest.client;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html